# NET TCP/HTTP WCF Hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, endpoint, net.tcp

I'm new to WCF and IIS but been doing some reading on how to host a WCF application in IIS. We have a system we're trying to deploy to IIS which needs HTTP and NET.TCP endpoints. I have everything configured as I saw in random tutorials but I still can't connect from my client. Any help with the configuration would be greatly appreciated!

My EdWCF.svc file in my WCF directory:

```
< %@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TwoFour.WCF.Engine.EdWCF" % >
```

My Web.Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata HttpGetEnabled="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

<service name="TwoFour.WCF.Engine.EdWCF" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviour">
       <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:12345/WCF/EdWCF.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
       </host>
       <endpoint address=""
                 binding="netTcpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="InsecureTcp"
                 contract="TwoFour.WCF.Interface.Shared.IEdWCF" />
       <endpoint address="mexhttp" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>

  <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="InsecureTcp" portSharingEnabled="true">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. In IIS add net.tcp binding into enabled protocols list (Mange Web Site -> Advance Settings -> Enabled Protocols)
2. In Site binding add net.tcp binding (Edit Binding -> Add -> Choose type as net.tcp and add port like this 12345:*)

You also need to specify Base address in your config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <services>
     <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="net.tcp://server:12345/ServiceAddress.svc"/>
       </baseAddresses>
     </host>
     ...
 </service>
     ...
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Edit:**

Try this

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

<service name="TwoFour.WCF.Engine.EdWCF" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviour">
       <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:12345/WCF/EdWCF.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
       </host>
       <endpoint address=""
                 binding="netTcpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="InsecureTcp"
                 contract="TwoFour.WCF.Interface.Shared.IEdWCF" />
       <endpoint address="mextcp" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>

  <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="InsecureTcp" portSharingEnabled="true">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I already had the bindings enabled, and I just added the host base address to my config file where the baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:12345/EdWCF.svc" - still not able to connect.

Comment: You need to add full address. If EdWCF.svc is in Engine folder change it to net.tcp://localhost:12345/Engine/EdWCF.svc

Comment: I have the Physical Path of my IIS Application set to C:\User\WCF\WCF thats where the EdWCF.svc file is located. I adjusted the base address to have net.tcp://localhost:12345/WCF/EdWCF.svc but when I try to connect from our client I still get : Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:12345/WCF/EdWCF.svc. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0052005. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:12345.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time out to try and help me troubleshoot this issue. I appreciate it very much. Unfortunately I'm still not having any luck. I get the same "connection refused" error message. I changed my config file to match the one you posted but for some reason, My connection isn't getting established. I double checked my bindings and NetTCP is listed and is an enabled protocol.

Comment: The physical path of my IIS application is C:\Franco Projects\WCF\WCF - EdWCF.svc and an EdWCF.svc.cs file in that directory. I modified my .svc file to have <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TwoFour.WCF.Engine.EdWCF" CodeBehind="EdWCF.svc.cs" %>. Not sure what part of my configuration is causing the connection to be refused.

Comment: CodeBehind="EdWCF.svc.cs" should be CodeBehind="TwoFour.WCF.Engine.EdWCF.svc.cs" if EdWCF class is in 'TwoFour.WCF.Engine' namespace.

Comment: Also please try to change mexTcpBinding to mexHttpBinding and add <serviceMetadata HttpGetEnabled="True" /> Let me know if it helps

Comment: I edited My original post with my new Web.Config file. After changing it, I get a new error message. Did I incorrectly edit the file? Now when trying to connect from my client I get: Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel/service. (C:\Franco Projects\WCF\WCF\web.config line 13)

Comment: Hm, still the same message. I tried removing that line entirely and I still got the same message pointing at the same line. Aside from adding that, I also changed the mexTcpBinding as you instructed, not sure if that's the problem. Again, thanks so much for the time and effort you've put in to help me.

Comment: In your config <services> </services> are missing :)  So it should be <services> <service>...</service> </services>

Comment: I had to remove the  HttpGetEnabled="true" because it kept saying it was an unrecognized attribute but after I did that, I was finally able to connect. Thanks so much buddy, your the man!