# NetTcpBinding in IIS: Unknown protocol ID 'net.tcp'

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, windows-server-2012, net.tcp

I'm trying to host a NetTcp endpoint for a WCF service but can seem to get it to work. Whenever I try to send a message to the endpoint, the application pool crashes and I get the follow error in the Event Log:

> An error occurred while trying to read and instantiate the configured ProcessHandlerType.
>
> Exception: System.ArgumentException
>
> Message: Unknown protocol ID 'net.tcp'.
>
> StackTrace:    at System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.StartProcessProtocolListenerChannel(String protocolId, IListenerChannelCallback listenerChannelCallback)

I'm using Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8. The application pool runs in .NET 2.0 Integrated Mode.
The Web Application has net.tcp as enabled protocol and the site that hosts the application has a net.tcp binding added with binding information 808:*. The feature Non-Http activation is enabled for .NET Framework 3.5 and the feature TCP activation is enabled for .NET Framework 4.5.

At first I couldn't get the NetTcp-endpoint working at all but with the help of the article located at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2803161 I managed to atleast GET the Mex http-endpoint. (I used Method 1 of the article).

Can anybody shed some light on a possible cause? Help would be much appreciated!

**Update:** When I change the application pool to .NET 4.0 integrated mode it works, unfortunately because of an old codebase, this brings other complications. So I still would like to make it work on a .NET 2.0 application pool.

Answer (score 1):

In order to host a WCF service with a netTcpBinding in IIS, the following extra configuration steps are required:

- Enable Non-HTTP Activation
- Configure IIS with “net.tcp” as an Enabled Protocol
- Specify a Site Binding that leverages the “net.tcp” binding type
- Add the base address to the web.config service configuration

The following articles provide additional details.
[NET TCP/HTTP WCF Hosted in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413406/net-tcp-http-wcf-hosted-in-iis)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/07/hosting-in-iis-using-nettcpbinding.aspx
http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2010/10/08/setting-up-a-nettcpbinding-enabled-wcf-service-in-iis-7.aspx

Comment: OP states that most if not all of the steps you listed have been done: **The Web Application has net.tcp as enabled protocol and the site that hosts the application has a net.tcp binding added with binding information 808:*. The feature Non-Http activation is enabled for .NET Framework 3.5 and the feature TCP activation is enabled for .NET Framework 4.5.**

Comment: Indeed, I'm already beyond these steps. I tried to isolate the problem by only hosting a NetTcp-endpoint and a NetTcp-MexEndpoint using a straightforward service servicebehavior. I keep getting the error from the OP in the event log.